# How to create Many-to-Many within the same table in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, associations, rails-activerecord

I just want to create a table (Domains: which contains Domains) in Rails which contains various fields: Id, Name (it contains domains and subdomains) and TLD(Top Level Domain). example: account.referal.com, in this account and referral, will be stored as separate values in the Name and com will be stored in TLD field. and domains and subdomains should have a many to many relationship within the same table and should form a URL from the table based on the relationship.

```
ask.facebook.com: ask => 1 facebook => 1

Domains Table
 ID
 Name
 TLD
Domain Relationship
 Parent.      Child.
 Domain Key.  Domain Key.
 1            1
```

by referencing to the ids and tld will create an url in future.

Comment: What is your question?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add another table (many-to-many) to hold the relationship for Domains table:

```
Class DomainChildren
      belongs_to :domain
      belongs_to :domain_child, class_name: 'Domain'
end


Class Domain
     has_many :domain_children     
End
```

Comment: @WuJo yes, It is a tree